# Auto center a table entry vertically and horizontally using tabularx

Tags: tables, tabularx

I wonder if it's possible to automatically center a table entry vertically and horizontally within a `tabularx` environment.

You can see that the matrix does not center:
[image: output]

The code I want to adjust is:

```
\begin{table}[h]
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}
\centering{\caption{Test Table}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X||c|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline          
        Holder1 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Holder2}& \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Holder3} & Holder4 \\
        %   \cline{2-5} 
        & $\boldsymbol{X}_1$    & $\boldsymbol{X}_1$ & $\boldsymbol{X}_2$ & {$\boldsymbol{X}_2$} & {Holder4 additional}\\
        \cline{1-6}
        abcv abcv abcv abcv abcv abcv ac sf abcv abcv & $\begin{bmatrix} W_{11}  \end{bmatrix}$   & $\begin{bmatrix} D_{11}  \end{bmatrix}$    & $\begin{bmatrix} K_{12}  \end{bmatrix}$    & 0  & 22\\
        \hline
        abcv abcv abcv abcv abcv abcv ac sf abcv abcv & $\begin{bmatrix} DD_{11} \\ Kl_{21}  \end{bmatrix}$      & $\begin{bmatrix} D_{11} \\ D_{21}  \end{bmatrix}$     & $\begin{bmatrix} X_{12} \\ S_{22}  \end{bmatrix}$    & 0  & 1\\
        \hline
        \text{text text text} & $\begin{bmatrix} G_{11} & G_{41} \\ G_{21} & G_{51} \\ W_{31} & O_{61} \end{bmatrix}$      & $\begin{bmatrix} G_{11} \\ G_{21} \\ G_{31}  \end{bmatrix}$   & $\begin{bmatrix} F_{12} \\ F_{12} \\ X_{12}  \end{bmatrix}$   & 0  & 3\\
        \hline  
    \end{tabularx}
    \label{}}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Is it for a single entry (I suppose the first column head) or for all entries in the column?

Comment: Hi Bernard, it should be for all entries. Especially for the entries with the matrix since they overlap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redefine the `X` column type as `m{#1}`. I added some vertical padding with `cellspace` and `extrarowheight` and gave a decent spacing between caption and table with the `caption` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularx, caption}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{4pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{4pt}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\centering}m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
  \caption{Test Table}
  \setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X||*{5}{Sc|}}
    \hline
    Holder1 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Holder2}& \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Holder3} & Holder4 \\
    \cline{2-5}
                                                         & $\boldsymbol{X}₁$ & $\boldsymbol{X}₁$ & $\boldsymbol{X}₂$ & {$\boldsymbol{X}₂$} & {Holder4 additional} \\
    \cline{1-6}
    \strut abcv abcv abcv abcv abcv abcv ac sf abcv abcv & $\begin{bmatrix} W_{11} \end{bmatrix}$ & $\begin{bmatrix} D_{11} \end{bmatrix}$ & $\begin{bmatrix} K_{12} \end{bmatrix}$ & 0 & 22 \\
    \hline
    abcv abcv abcv abcv abcv abcv ac sf abcv abcv & $\begin{bmatrix} DD_{11} \\ Kl_{21} \end{bmatrix}$ & $\begin{bmatrix} D_{11} \\ D_{21} \end{bmatrix}$ & $\begin{bmatrix} X_{12} \\ S_{22} \end{bmatrix}$ & 0 & 1 \\
    \hline
    \text{text text text} & $\begin{bmatrix} G_{11} & G_{41} \\ G_{21} & G_{51} \\ W_{31} & O_{61} \end{bmatrix}$ & $\begin{bmatrix} G_{11} \\ G_{21} \\ G_{31} \end{bmatrix}$ & $\begin{bmatrix} F_{12} \\ F_{12} \\ X_{12} \end{bmatrix}$ & 0 & 3 \\
    \hline
  \end{tabularx}
  \label{}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Bernard, do you know why I get the following errors using your code?:

siunitx error: "duplicate-exponent-token" Duplicate exponent marker token '\token_to_str:N e' in input. For immediate help type H <return>. \end{tabularx}
--------------------
siunitx error: "invalid-number" Invalid numerical input 'de'. For immediate help type H <return>. \end{tabularx}
--------------------
Emergency stop. \end{tabularx}

Comment: This did not happen with just my code, since it doesn't use `siunitx`. Could you post a (full) minimal example code reproducing the error?

Comment: Yes you are right, it works if I simply execute your code. If I add the \usepackage{siunitx} it throws an error

Comment: @Zeit: I had forgotten: that is due to the `S` pre-qualifier used by `cellspace` to ensure padding in the corresponding columns, as it is also defined as a column type by `siunitx`. The solution is explained in the documentation of the latter package: use the pre-qualifier `C` instead–hoping you don't already have to use a `C` column type…

Comment: That is a great comment! Now it is simply perfect with the C pre-qualifier :) Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,ngerman]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.7}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X||c|c|c|c|c|}        \hline          
    Holder1 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Holder2}& \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Holder3} & Holder4 \\
    %   \cline{2-5} 
    & $\boldsymbol{X}_1$    & $\boldsymbol{X}_1$ & $\boldsymbol{X}_2$ & 
    {$\boldsymbol{X}_2$} & {Holder4 additional}\\
    \cline{1-6}
    abcv abcv abcv abcv abcv abcv ac sf abcv abcv & $\begin{bmatrix} W_{11}  
    \end{bmatrix}$   & $\begin{bmatrix} D_{11}  \end{bmatrix}$    & $\begin{bmatrix} 
    K_{12}  \end{bmatrix}$    & 0  & 22\\
    \hline
    abcv abcv abcv abcv abcv abcv ac sf abcv abcv & $\begin{bmatrix} DD_{11} \\ 
    Kl_{21}  \end{bmatrix}$      & $\begin{bmatrix} D_{11} \\ D_{21}  
    \end{bmatrix}$     & $\begin{bmatrix} X_{12} \\ S_{22}  \end{bmatrix}$    & 0  & 
    1\\
    \hline
    \strut\text{text text text} & $\begin{bmatrix} G_{11} & G_{41} \\ G_{21} & G_{51} 
    \\ 
    W_{31} & O_{61} \end{bmatrix}$      & $\begin{bmatrix} G_{11} \\ G_{21} \\ 
    G_{31}  \end{bmatrix}$   & $\begin{bmatrix} F_{12} \\ F_{12} \\ X_{12}  
    \end{bmatrix}$   & 0  & 3\\
    \hline  
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, I wouldn't use all the vertical lines.

Comment: Thank you very much Herbert, it looks much better now. Do you think it is also possible to add extra space between the brackets of the matrix and the horizontal lines? Especially the last row is quite close to the this line.

Comment: for the last row use something like `\rule[-1cm]{0pt}{2cm}\text{text text text} & ... `. It is an invisible vertical line